# "Unused import: Image" error when trying to import a function

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library

I downloaded Pillow using pip and am trying to import its Image package to use the rotate function that is in the Image package, but when I use

```
from PIL import Image
```

I get an

```
Unused import: Image
```

error along with a

```
found at PIL.Image 1
```

message. Does anybody know what this means or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What python version are you using and what command are you running? Are you just doing `from PIL import Image` in the python interpreter?